# Is there a simple function that generates the series: 1/1, 1/2, 2/1, 1/3, 2/2, 3/1, 1/4, 2/3, 3/2, 4/1 ...

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, functions

It's a sequence that generates all positive rational numbers.

I have worked out one:
$$a_n=\frac{n-\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{\sqrt {8n}-1}{2}\rfloor} i}
{\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{\sqrt {8n}+1}{2}\rfloor} i-n+1}$$

It does work, but it's too complex.

I wonder is there any simple functions that can generate this sequence?

Comment: Another function which gives all rational numbers is the inverse Cantor pairing function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function. But I don't know in which sequence they are listed.

Comment: "$n$-th term is $n - m(m+1)/2 + 1$, where $m = \lfloor(\sqrt{8n+1} - 1) / 2\rfloor$." according to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A002260) about the sequence $1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,\ldots$ (your numerators). I don't think it can be done much easier.